# UIImagePicker saving photos to multiple albums

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, photolibrary

Im am trying to capture images and save them to a custom album using UIImagePickerController.TMy problem is that the images are getting saved into the following albums

1) My custom album
2)Camera Roll 
3) My Photo Stream

I am using the following code for the image saving part

```
//Save image in an album with the app's name
        _assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [_assetsLibrary saveImage:imageToSave toAlbum:@"My Album" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error!=nil) {
                DLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
```

How can i prevent the photos from getting saved as multiple copies??

Comment: May be I am mistaken, but I think this is standard behavior

Comment: I think so too.But that means a lot of wasted space.Also from my app the user can delete photos.In this case the photo gets deleted only from my album.The other two copies remain in the device.Certainly undesirable